# What is the current state of the art in Multi-View Clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, unsupervised-learning

Many real-world datasets have representations in the form of multiple views. For example, a person can be identified by face, fingerprint, signature and iris or an image that can be represented by its color and texture features. Multi-view is basically information obtained from multiple sources. In the context of machine learning/data clustering/computer vision, what are the most relevant applications that deal with this approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of computer vision **multi-view** refers to the images of the same object taken from different views/angles/positions. There are multiple applications of this strategy. [3D reconstruction from multiple view](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~snavely/bundler/) is one of the most popular examples.

The type of **multi-view** you are referring to is basically **data augmentation** to solve a single problem. As you have mentioned too, identification of a person from different kind of data-sources is an application of **data-augmentation**. There can be multiple other applications too. For example expression estimation, to identify the mood of a person, using data from a RGB camera + 3D data from Kinect + Audio is another example.

In the context of machine-learning **data-augmentation** is everywhere. Combining different features of an image or audio for classification is **data-augmentation**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would appreciate if you could provide some articles or good references about it.